# array of buttons in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, arrays, button

Hey guys, I want to layout a group of buttons on the window. What I want is connecting those buttons to a "buttons array" I set up in the controller class. Is there a faster way to do the connection in the IB? I know one way to do that is to layout those buttons programmatically, but somehow I am not quite familiar with the view architecture under Cocoa.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're on the mac, check out [`NSMatrix`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html).